# Fastest way to update multiple rows in a MySQL database with no unique indexes

Tags: mysql, performance

I need to update a large number of rows in a single database, as quickly as possible. Each row has a generated "key" field which is NOT guaranteed to be unique; if multiple rows have the same key they may all be updated with the same values.

If the keys were unique, I would do this using an INSERT VALUES ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE method.  Unfortunately, the database in question has no unique keys and I am unable to add any, so I need a different solution.

The simplest solution is to simply write a different update statement for each item and send them one after another:

```
UPDATE my_table SET field1=value1_1, field2=value2_2, field3=value3_3 WHERE key=1;
UPDATE my_table SET field1=value1_2, field2=value2_2, field3=value3_2 WHERE key=2;
```

But this would require thousands of independent queries.

Another option is to merge them all into a single query using CASE WHEN:

```
UPDATE my_table SET field1 = 
    CASE WHEN key=1 THEN value_1_1 
    ELSE WHEN key=2 THEN value_1_2
    END ,
field2 = 
    CASE WHEN key=1 THEN value_2_1 
    ELSE WHEN key=2 THEN value_2_2
    END ,
field3 = 
    CASE WHEN key=1 THEN value_3_1 
    ELSE WHEN key=2 THEN value_3_2
    END
```

Finally, there's this method of effectively building a fake temporary table and joining it together with the real one:

```
UPDATE my_table t1 JOIN (
    (SELECT 1 AS key, value_1_1 AS field1_new, value_2_1 AS field2_new, value_3_1 AS field3_new) UNION ALL
    (SELECT 2, value_1_2, value_2_2, value_3_2)
) vals ON t1.key = vals.key SET field1 = field1_new, field2 AS field2_new, field3 AS field3_new
```

(For the latter two methods, I can break up the list into chunks of a few hundred rows to avoid going over the limit for long queries.)

So the question is, which is the fastest method to use? And is there another one that I don't know about?

Comment: What's the question? Are you trying to update every key row but are encountering timeouts? You don't know all the key values? You think chunking the updates is a solution? How many rows need updating out of how many? please add table definition in full including engine, collation and partition information..

Comment: I'm updating every row and it is increasing server latency while the query is happening.  I am trying to mitigate this as much as possible.

Comment: You have the data for updating in some form... in what form? I think that the fastest way is: create temptable with the data for updation, update with multiple-table query, drop temptable. If the amount of data is not too large then temptable engine should be MEMORY.

Comment: But this would require thousands of independent queries. -  true, have you considered dynamic sql to build the update statements within a procedure called by an event?